# How can I list enum values and concatenate id in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
public enum  DocumentType {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D;
}
```

I want a list like this:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate a little. You might want to look at methods like `values()`, `ordinal()` and `name()`. Use those to construct the list. Since those enums wouldn't change you could also create that list only once, cache it somewhere and then reuse it in your endpoint. It's hard to help more without knowing what _exactly_ you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure why you want this. But `IntStream.range(0, DocumentType.values().length).mapToObj(i -> (i + 1) + " " + DocumentType.values()[i]).forEach(System.out::println);` will do.

Comment: @MCEmperor Shorter: `for (var v : DocumentType.values()) {System.out.println((v.ordinal() + 1) + " " + v);}`

Answer (score 2):

```
public class EnumId {
    public enum DocumentType {
        A(1), B(2), C(3), D(4);

        final int id;

        DocumentType(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (DocumentType dt : DocumentType.values())
            System.out.println(dt.getId() + " " + dt.name());
    }
}
```

```
$ javac EnumId.java
$ java EnumId      
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
$
```

Comment: This is good, but I think your field `int id` should be `final int id`.

Comment: @davidalayachew Thanks, `final` makes sense in this case. Added.

Answer (score 2):

You can even use `ordinal` & `name` methods available in `Enum`; this don't need you to modify anything in existing `DocumentType` :

```
for(DocumentType e:DocumentType.values()) {
            System.out.println((e.ordinal()+1)+" "+e.name());
}
```

Output:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to return this in a response you could do something like this:

```java
public String yourEndpoit() {
    final DocumentType[] values = DocumentType.values();

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        builder.append(i)
                .append(" ")
                .append(values[i])
                .append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
        
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that leverages method declarations within enumerated types:

```java
public enum DocumentType {
    A, B, C, D;
    
    public String asListItem() {
        return String.format("%d %s", ordinal()+1, name());
    }
    
    public static String toList() {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .map(DocumentType::asListItem)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
}
```

To get the list: `DocumentType.toList()`.